# EMF in coils outside a solenoid

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

As a follow up to [How does the emf "know" what the magnetic flux is?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/221535/).

The distance from the solenoid to the external loop appears to have no influence on the EMF induced in the loop, or have I missed something?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, you could worry because the induced electric field decreases when one moves away from the axis of the solenoid. But the length of the path increases in the same proportions and the induced emf $\int{\vec{E}\vec{dl}}$ does not change.

Answer (score 0):

The magnetic field lines are confined to the interior of the solenoid, so even though the coil has a larger area, the flux through the coil is the same as the flux through the solenoid